# HTML table row link open in new tab

Tags: javascript, html-table, row

I'm trying to add link to table row and open new tab when clicked.

Solution below works, but i need to open page in new tab.

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#orders-table tr').click(function () {
        var href = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
        if (href) { window.location = href; }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```html
<tr href="/order?id=[ORDER_ID_LOCAL]" target="_blank">
```

Comment: Is that a `tr` tag with `href` and `target` attributes? You can edit your question to best describe your usage. It could be confusing this way.

Comment: FYI: The HTML contain no `<a>`, and line 3 expects that (`.find("a")`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open), [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) or [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) instead of `var` and proper indentation. Also remove the `href` and `target` attributes from the `tr` HTML tag.

Answer (score 0):

`window.open` to the rescue.

Use

`var href = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
window.open(href, '_blank');`

add the above lines inside click callback and it will open href link in new tab.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use window.open instead of window.loction

```
window.open(
  href,
  '_blank' // <- This is what makes it open in a new window.
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery snippet expects the HTML to contain a link anywhere in the `<tr>`, like this:

```html
<tr>
  <td>
    <a href="/order?id=[ORDER_ID_LOCAL]" target="_blank">Item excerpt</a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Also, use `window.open()` instead since this will let the user decide if the click should go to another Window or tab.

Answer (score 0):

To make a table row clickable is very straightforward with bootstrap 4 using a stretched link. Stretched links fill the entire space of the container they are in that has a relative position and since tables naturally don't have a relative position, we have to add this as a class (comes with bootstrap) to the Table rows. CSS can be used to further adjust the rows to look anyhow you want. Here is an example code:

```
<table class="table dataTable my-0">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="position-relative">
            <td>
                <a class="stretched-link" href="#" target="_blank">Name</a>
            </td>
            <td>Office</td>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td>Last Login</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```